# Are there any bugs or fish to be found on main street?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

On Main Street in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf* are there ever any bugs around or any fish in the pond?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, bugs won't spawn there. The trees and pond are fake, I don't believe you can even cast your rod in the pond. Bugs/fish only spawn in town, on the Island or during Island Tours (and only certain tours have catchable animals.)

Comment: Edits shouldn't change the information presented in a post, even if incorrect.